# Lua: use table as args

Tags: lua, runtime, arguments

I have numerous functions (unknown at design time) that each take a specific number of arguments. I have a table of arguments. How do I call those functions with this table of arguments?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `unpack()`:

```
function test(a,b,c)
   print(a+b+c)
end

myargs = {1,2,3}

test(unpack(myargs)) -- prints "6"
```

Comment: In some more recent version of Lua (not sure which), the `unpack()` function was moved into the `table` table. So, the example becomes `test(table.unpack(myargs))`